# Do not use UIImagePickerController Get photos

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to get photos from the Photo Gallery but do not want to use UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ALAssets library, here is an example 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you, but NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
To add ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos